# Python: I'm making a simple calculator for class. What's wrong with this code?

Tags: python, calculator

My teacher requests me to make a calculator that can calculate a 15% tip on a submitted price. I followed an online tutorial for this python application. I made a simple addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division calculator for practice before I make what my teacher requires. In the YouTube video I followed the python application ran on his computer. I get a a "Invalid Syntax" error in the Python Shell. I'm using Python 3.3.0. Thank you.

---

```
print "Hello"
def calc():
    x = int (raw_input("Input first integer: "))
    y = (raw_input("Input second integer: "))
    type = str.lower(raw_input("(A)dd, (S)ubstract, (M)ultiply, (D)ivide"))
    if type != "a" and type != "s" and type != "m" and type != "d":
        print ("Sorry, the command you entered is not calid.")
        calc():
    else:
        if type =="a":
            print ("The result is '" + str(x+y) + "'")
        elif type == "s":
            print ("The result is '" + str(x-y) + "'")
        elif type =="m":
            print ("The result is '" + str(x*y) + "'")
        elif type == "d":
            print ("The result is '" + str(float(x)/float(y) + "'")

        if str.lower (raw_input ("Would you like to perform another calculation?") == "y"):
            calc();
        else:
            exit([0])
calc();
```

Comment: What line are you getting a syntax error on?

Answer (score 1):

because y is string

```
y = int(raw_input("Input second integer: "))
```

Comment: They say in their question that they are using python 3.3

Comment: I have formatted your answer -- you can do that with the `{}`-button above the textarea

Comment: What seems to happen is, possibly, the tutorial I was following was not using Python 3.x. Is there anything I wrote that should be changed for 3.x language standards?

Comment: that's right  if you were using python 2.x you could use input directly instead of int(raw_input('...')) .. but input is not available in python 3.x ,, input in 2.x job is evaluate the expression   ,, you could read more about it

Comment: @ComplexCode your answer is wrong; he's asking about Python 3.x, not 2.x. Additionally, input should never be used (unless you absolutely know what you're doing) in python 2.x. Furthermore, raw_input was changed to input in 3.x, which means that input() is very much available.

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple problems with your code.

Your use of `print` on the first line will give you troubles, because `print` is a function in Python 3. You should call it like `print("hello")`.

On line 8, you have an extra colon:

```
calc():
```

Get rid of that.

Last, you don't need the semicolons when you call `calc()`

Answer (score 0):

This has a lot of changes to do.
First, the first line of code should be:

```
print ("Hello")
```

Then, the raw_input() should become input().

Next, there should not be a colon or semicolon after calc() except on the second line when you are defining a function.

The code should look something like this. Try it.

```
print ("Hello")
def calc():
    x = int(input("Input first integer: "))
    y = int(input("Input second integer: "))
    type = str.lower(input("(A)dd, (S)ubstract, (M)ultiply, (D)ivide \n"))
    if type != "a" and type != "s" and type != "m" and type != "d":
        print ("Sorry, the command you entered is not valid.")
        calc()
    else:
        if type =="a":
            print ("The result is '" + str(x+y) + "'")
        elif type == "s":
            print ("The result is '" + str(x-y) + "'")
        elif type =="m":
            print ("The result is '" + str(x*y) + "'")
        elif type == "d":
            print ("The result is '" + str(float(x)/float(y)) + "'")

        if int(input("Enter 1 if you would like to perform another calculation? \n")) == 1:
            calc()
        else:
            exit()
calc()
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of converting to int (thus flooring whatever your value is -- 2.99 becomes 2, for instance) converting to float should do the trick nicely; the tip calculation should work even if you're doing 2.0*0.15 instead of 2*0.15.

This will obviously only work when you know what input you can expect. It will fail pretty badly if someone enters anything that isn't valid.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use integer:

```
mealprice = int(input("Enter your meal price:"))
```

If you want to use float:

```
mealprice = float(input("Enter your meal price:"))
```

Float is recommended because You can also use a single number like 1,2,3 etc and also float numbers.

I also created my own calculator that has 6 functions:

```
1 = Add  
2 = Subtract  
3 = Multiply  
4 = Divide  
5 = Round Off  
6 = Get Remainder
```

It is so simple.
I have Not Used Round Off yet.
If You want That code Ask me I will give you.
If you want more Info, I am ready to Provide To you.

Comment: Here the calculator [link](https://ufile.io/w4ts1).It will expire after 30 days..

Comment: Check new link to [calculator](https://www.protectedtext.com/mycalculator).type password: **password1**. copy the code paste it on your idle.And Enjoy.

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out. I was supposed to use:

```
int(float(input("Enter your meal price:")))
```

Thank you, everyone!