# Python: Allowing "$" sign in front of float integers

Tags: python, calculator

How do I allow someone to enter a float integer with a "$" in front of the value. For example, they could enter "$4.25" and also they could enter "4.25".

Also, when I enter "4.35" into my calculator the tip comes out as "0.6". On a calculator I own at home it comes out as 0.6525. How do I get the whole answer?

```
input ('Please Enter to begin')

while True:
    print('This calculator will display the tip you owe for your meal price.')
    mealPrice = int(float(input('Enter your meal price:')))
    asw = mealPrice * 0.15
    print('The tip you owe is: $',asw)

    endProgram = input ('Do you want to restart the program?')

    if endProgram in ('no', 'No', 'NO', 'false', 'False', 'FALSE'):
        break
```

Comment: Is this Python 3 or 2.X?

Comment: Incidentally, why are you casting the `float` to an `int`? That truncates the price to the nearest dollar, which isn't necessary (if you left it as a float it would calculate it as an exact tip)

Comment: To expand on @DavidRobinson's point about `int` not being desirable, you can to limit the output to two decimal places using string formatting: `print("The tip you owe is: ${:.2f}".format(asw))`

Comment: Did you just ask this earlier? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14611344/python-im-making-a-simple-calculator-for-class-whats-wrong-with-this-code/14612909#14612909

Answer (score 5):

Change

```
mealPrice = int(float(input('Enter your meal price:')))
```

to

```
mealPrice = float(input('Enter your meal price:').lstrip("$"))
```

`lstrip("$")` removes any occurrences of the given character from the left side of the string. You also need to remove the `int`, which truncates the price to the nearest dollar (and is the reason you're getting the wrong answer sometimes).

Comment: aren't you supposed to use "input instead of "raw_input" in Python 3.3.0? Anyway, this worked. Thank you.

Comment: @Blckknght: I wasn't sure about Python 3 (while it's true that the OP wouldn't need `float(` in Python 3, the OP also doesn't need `int`, so I figured it's possible both calls are unnecessary). However, given that the print statements are used as a function that takes two arguments I do agree that it's probably Python 3.

Comment: @JordanSimps: That's the reason I asked `Is this Python 3 or 2.X?` in a comment

Comment: @DavidRobinson you need either float() or int(), since input returns strings.

Comment: @RobertS.: Typo- comment should have been `wouldn't need float in Python 2`